Suspected memory leaked but can't solve it
To start, I got a problem where there are unknown memory usages that not shown in Task Manager nor Resource Monitor.


So, I look out for the similar problem here and found this post here.
I followed the answer of the post, and got myself the suspected causes.


I looked into the causes files and it was these 2



Then I check their properties to see the product name:


After that I tried to install the newest version of Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology (IRST).
But the problem is not solved and then it turn out that IRST is non-to-be-found in anywhere.
I tried install it couple of times and reboot quite a lot, nothing works.

Is there any solution to fix this problem? I do need to use some amount of RAM lately.

Unless you have Intel IST enabled.  Why do you have the even driver installed? Your screenshot with the output locating drivers, cannot be dicphered, why isn't it in English?

To be honest, I don't even know how or when does the IRST installed in the first place. And about the output, as the guide that someone answered in the attached link I gave, they got the same ciphered text just like me. Though they don't explain why it is ciphered.

Intel RST would only have been installed by a human, if you don't have it enabled within the firmware, and did not installed Windows on a Intel RST enabled disk then it can be uninstalled.

But as I told in the post that IRST is non to be found in anywhere, so I can't uninstall it nor update it. But their driver keep using up my memory resources.

You can run a command to delete the driver. You just need to know the inf file name

You can use pnputil /enum-drivers to identify the driver.
